# Is calling Runtime.getRuntime().exec(), the proper way to execute an OS command continually?

Tags: java, runtime

Looking to execute an OS command on Linux continually using a Java routine.

The following is an example of executing **"ls /tmp/MyNewFile.tx"** and works. Eventually it will run in a loop continually until the file appears.

This is just an example as the OS command executing will vary, but in every case the code will continually loop.

The concern is that this process would run continually which results in the rapid creation and destroying of Processes at the OS level. Are there any concerns with that happening?

Is there a more efficient or proper means for accomplishing this?

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;

public class MyTest
{
    public static void main(String[] arguments)
    {
        try
        {

                        String[] cmd_check = {
                            "/bin/sh",
                            "-c",
                            "ls /tmp/MyNewFile.tx" 
                        };
                /*************Create LOOP to continually check for a file****************/
                Process p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(cmd_check);
                System.out.println(p.toString());
                InputStream stdIn = p.getInputStream();
                InputStreamReader isr = new InputStreamReader(stdIn);
                BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(isr);

                String line = null;
                System.out.println("<OUTPUT>");

                while ((line = br.readLine()) != null)
                     System.out.println(line);

                System.out.println("</OUTPUT>");
                int exitVal = p.waitFor();
                System.out.println("Process exitValue: " + exitVal);

        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What are you actually trying to do? Why not just use a Java file system operation? But there should be nothing wrong with running your code in a loop (make sure that Process.waitFor() implies that the processes Java IO streams are closed)

Comment: Think of it as a secondary process and needs to know immediately when a certain directory and or file is created in order to do some work.

Comment: The [Files.exists](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/15/docs/api/java.base/java/nio/file/Files.html#exists(java.nio.file.Path,java.nio.file.LinkOption...)) method is considerably more efficient than creating a new shell.  And Files.exists will work on all operating systems.

Comment: ok, thanks for the info.  The main objective is to know if continually executing the code in the loop cause any issues as it rapidly creates and kills processes.